# Java Pong Game Collision Detection Issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I am fairly new to Java and could use some help. I've created the Pong game (using Eclipse), and for the most part, it functions quite well. However, something is not right with the collision detection. The ball bounces off the human-controlled paddle just fine, but always passes right through the AI-controlled paddle, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong in my code. Here's the code:

The main class, "Tennis":

```
package PongV2;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


public class Tennis extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener{
final int WIDTH = 700, HEIGHT = 500;
Thread thread;
HumanPaddle p1;
AIPaddle p2;
Ball b1;
boolean gameStarted;
Graphics gfx;
Image img;


public void init(){
     this.resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
     gameStarted = false;
     this.addKeyListener(this);
     p1 = new HumanPaddle(1);
     b1 = new Ball();
     p2 = new AIPaddle(2, b1);
     img = createImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
     gfx = img.getGraphics();
     thread = new Thread(this);
     thread.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    gfx.setColor(Color.black);
    gfx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    if(b1.getX() < -10 || b1.getX() > 710){
        gfx.setColor(Color.red);
        gfx.drawString("Game Over", 350, 250);
    }
    else{
    p1.draw(gfx);
    b1.draw(gfx);
    p2.draw(gfx);
}

    if(!gameStarted) {
        gfx.setColor(Color.white);
        gfx.drawString("Pong", 343, 100);
        gfx.drawString("Press Enter to Begin...", 295, 130);
    }
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);

}


public void update(Graphics g){
    paint(g);
}

public void run() {
    for(;;){
         if(gameStarted) {
        p1.move();
        p2.move();
        b1.move();
        b1.checkPaddleCollision(p1, p2);
         }
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
       p1.setUpAccel(true);
    } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        p1.setDownAccel(true);
    } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        gameStarted = true;

}
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        p1.setUpAccel(false);
    } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        p1.setDownAccel(false);
    }

}


public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

}

}
```

Also a look at the "AIPaddle" class, if anyone needs to see it:

```
package PongV2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class AIPaddle implements Paddle{
double y, yVel;
boolean upAccel, downAccel;
final double GRAVITY = 0.94;
int player, x;
Ball b1;

public AIPaddle(int player, Ball b){
    upAccel = false; downAccel = false;
    b1 = b;
    y = 210; yVel = 0;
    if(player == 1)
        x = 20;
    else
        x = 660;
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(x, (int)y, 20, 80);

}

public void move() {
    y = b1.getY() -40;


     if(y < 0)
         y = 0;
     if(y > 420)
         y = 420;

}


public int getY() {
    return (int)y;
}

}
```

"Ball" class:

```
package PongV2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Ball {
double xVel, yVel, x, y;

public Ball(){
    x = 350;
    y = 250;
    xVel = getRandomSpeed() * getRandomDirection();
    yVel = getRandomSpeed() * getRandomDirection();
}

public double getRandomSpeed(){
    return(Math.random() *3 + 2);
}

public int getRandomDirection(){
    int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
    if(rand == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.white); 
    g.fillOval((int)x-10, (int)y-10, 20, 20);
}

public void checkPaddleCollision(Paddle p1, Paddle p2){
    if (x <= 50){
       if(y >= p1.getY() && y <= p1.getY() + 80){
           xVel = -xVel;
}
    else if(x >= 650){
        if(y >= p2.getY() && y <= p2.getY() + 80)
            xVel = -xVel;
    }
    }
}

public void move(){
    x += xVel;
    y += yVel;

    if(y < 10)
        yVel = -yVel;
    if(y > 490)
        yVel = -yVel;
}

public int getX(){
    return (int)x;
}

public int getY(){
    return (int)y;
}

}
```

Could someone please advise where my code needs to be corrected? Thanks.

Comment: is some error being thrown?

Comment: No, no errors. It starts up and everything, the ball just passes through the AI paddle - no collision detection. But it bounces off the human-controlled paddle just fine. Can't figure out where the error in the code is.

Comment: try using a debugger then.

Comment: b1.checkPaddleCollision(p1, p2); is crucial - the rest seems fun in the park

Comment: Could you post your Ball class?

Comment: I edited the post to include the Ball class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the if statement in your checkPaddleCollisionMethod. You have this right now.

```
if(...) {
    if(...) {
    }
    else if(...) {
        if(...) {
        }
    }
}
```

The else if is parallel to the second if, not the first. You want a structure more like this.

```
if(...) {
    if(...) {
    }
}
else if(...) {
    if(...) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thank you! Seems like my mistakes are always over the curly braces, lol.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Since this solved your problem, you should mark it as an accepted/best answer to signify you don't need more answers. This is done by clicking the check mark button under the up and down vote buttons.